# Why is it called Nematocyst "Battery"?

Tags: zoology

I was reading an article on Hydra where they mentioned Nematocyst Battery. I know that Hydra and other Cnidarians have nematocyst but why are they called Nematocyst 'Battery'?

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Can you add that reference?

Comment: sorry I cannot give you the reference right now. But i googled it and found this where the writer also called it the "Battery of Nematocyst" http://www.iaszoology.com/nematocysts/

Comment: Since cnidae are "single use" cells, and this costs a lot of energy, in order to regulate discharge, cnidocytes are connected as "batteries", containing several types of cnidocytes connected to supporting cells and neurons (from Wikipedia)

Comment: A battery generally refers to a series. E.g., a test battery is a (generally quite large) set of (related) tests. In this case you can replace "test" by "nematocyst" I guess. But I haven't looked at the link yet.

Comment: So it just means series and not related to energy source?